# Integral of Continuous and Increasing Function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $f: [0,b] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and increasing and $f(0)=0$. let $g$ denote the inverse of f. Then show that

$\int_0^b f(t)dt + \int_0^{f(b)} g(t)dt = f(b)b.$

Comment: Have you tried drawing a picture?

Comment: Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Yes I tried drawing a picture and I see that obviously $g(x)=f'(x)$ and $f(g(x))=x$ and $g(f(x))=x.$

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, the proof of this proposition is really obvious if you draw the right picture. Try drawing what represents the integral of $f(t)$ from $0$ to $b$. Is there something on that picture you can relate to the integral of $g$?

(Hint: how is the graph of $g$ related to the graph of $f$?)